# Testing form inputs in PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

What's the best way to test `$_GET` and `$_POST` inputs in `PHPUnit`?

I have a class that sanitises input and want to check that it works correctly when processing bogus data.  Is there an easy way to set up the form variables in `PHPUnit` or should I just pass off the validation to a secondary class/functions that are fed the form variables so test them indirectly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at the idea of [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). In a nutshell you should feed your code what it needs as opposed to it getting the data it needs... Here's an example:

example without Dependency Injection

```
function sanitize1() {
  foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    // code to sanitize $v
  }
}

sanitize1();
```

example with Dependency Injection

```
function sanitize2(array &$formData) {
  foreach($formData as $k => $v) {
    // code to sanitize $v
  }
}

sanitize2($_POST);
```

See the difference? In your PHPUnit test you can pass `sanitize2()` an associative array of your choice; you've injected the dependency. Whereas `sanitize1()` is coupled with `$_POST`. `$_POST` and `$_GET` are assoc arrays anyways so in your production code you can pass `$_GET` or `$_POST` to your function but in your unit tests you'd hard code some expected data.

Unit test example:

```
function testSanitize() {
  $fakeFormData = array ('bio' => 'hi i\'m arin', 'location' => 'San Francisco');
  sanitize($fakeFormData);
  // assert something
}
```